Is piping a boost::iterator_range backed up by std::list into ranges::views::transform(f) | ranges::to_vector valid code?
Here is the code:
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;
int main()
{
    std::list<int> v;
    auto r = boost::make_iterator_range(v);
    auto w = r
           | transform([](auto x){ return x; })
           | to_vector;
}

It does not compile for c++20, the error being copied two code snippets below.
Either of these actions makes it compile

change std::list to std::vector,
make r const,
compile for c++17,
compile with Clang.

What is the correct behavior, Clang's or GCC's, according to c++20 and c++17?
Here are the variations described above on Compiler Explorer.
I'm more and more convinced this is a bug in GCC. I've been told it's not, but I  can't really get my head around the arguments listed from those answers.
Original question Left here because contains additional information
I've stripped an example down to the following:
#include <boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <range/v3/view/ref.hpp>

int main() {
    std::list<int> l;
    using Foo = const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<decltype(l.begin())>>&;
    ranges::_size_::has_non_member_size<Foo>;
}

which

with -std=c++20 compiles with GCC <= 10.5 and fails to compile with GCC >= 11.1,
with -std=c++17 compiles in both cases.

The error starts like this, and it seems to refer to a concept that requires itself (see the first link above for the full error):
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/view/ref.hpp:17,
                 from <source>:3:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/range/traits.hpp: In substitution of 'template<class R>  requires (!(has_member_size<R>) || (disable_sized_range<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::type>)) && (!(has_non_member_size<R>) || (disable_sized_range<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::type>)) && (forward_iterator<decltype({}(static_cast<R&& (*)()noexcept (true)>(nullptr)()))>) && (sized_sentinel_for<decltype({}(static_cast<R&& (*)()noexcept (true)>(nullptr)())), decltype({}(static_cast<R&& (*)()noexcept (true)>(nullptr)()))>) constexpr ranges::_size_::fn::_result_t<R> ranges::_size_::fn::operator()(R&&) const [with R = const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > >&]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/range/traits.hpp:76:47:   required by substitution of 'template<class Rng> using range_size_t = decltype (ranges::_::size(declval<Rng&>())) [with Rng = const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > >]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/meta/meta_fwd.hpp:286:18:   required by substitution of 'template<template<class ...> class C, class ... Ts>  requires  valid<C, Ts ...> struct meta::detail::defer_<C, Ts ...> [with C = ranges::range_size_t; Ts = {const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > >}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/meta/meta.hpp:788:12:   required from 'struct meta::defer<ranges::range_size_t, const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > > >'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/view/ref.hpp:121:1:   required from 'struct boost::range_size<const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > > >'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_85_0/boost/range/size.hpp:55:5:   required by substitution of 'template<class SinglePassRange> typename boost::range_size<const SinglePassRange>::type boost::size(const SinglePassRange&) [with SinglePassRange = ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > >]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/range/primitives.hpp:63:9:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/range/primitives.hpp:63:9:   required for the satisfaction of 'has_non_member_size_requires_<T>' [with T = const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > >&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/range/primitives.hpp:63:9:   in requirements with 'T&& t' [with T = const ranges::ref_view<boost::iterator_range<std::_List_iterator<int> > >&]
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/range/primitives.hpp:63:9: error: satisfaction of atomic constraint 'requires(T&& t) {ranges::_size_::size((T&&(t)));} [with T = T]' depends on itself
   63 |         CPP_requires(has_non_member_size_,
      |         ^

Some observations:

removing const from the definition of the Foo alias fixes the compilation failure;
keeping that const and changing std::list to std::vector also fixes the compilation failure;
I've got lost in the macro black magic occurring between <range/v3/range/primitives.hpp> and <concepts/concepts.hpp>;

I think that ranges::_size_::has_non_member_size<Foo>; resolves to ranges::_size_::has_non_member_size_requires_<Foo>;, and clangd tells me, if I understand it (which I don't think I do!), that is equivalent to
template <typename T>
concept has_non_member_size_requires_ = requires(T &&t) { size((T &&)t); }

but if I just write such a concept before main and substitute it into the last line of the original snippet, I don't get a compilation failure.



Can somebody enlighten me on what's happening?

adding volatile to the Foo definition (const volatile ranges...) also fixes the compilation failure.

Always post "complete error" along with your question. At least one error message should be posted in a post asking about cause of said error.

@user12002570, it is visible in the links to compiler explorer I provided. Anyway, I've copied what I think is the interesting part of it.
